# Filter a list with multiple conditions using WITH in Cypher,Neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I'm new to Neo4j. I'm kind of got stuck for loading a JSON file into Neo4j database.
I have a list of tags for many transactions. Each transaction tag can have one or two tags: third-party and category.

Here is an example JSON.

```
{
    "tags": [
        [
            {
                "thirdParty": "Supermarkets"
            },
            {
                "category": "Groceries"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "category": "Rent"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "thirdParty": "Education"
            },
            {
                "category": "Education"
            }
        ]
        .....
    ]
}
```

I only want to find objects that have both category and thirdParty(some objects only have one tag).

And here is my code, the list is just a list of categories I want.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///full.json")
YIELD value
with ['Gambling','Subscription TV','Telecommunications'] as list
UNWIND value.tags as tags
WITH [tag in tags where tag.category IN list AND tag.thirdParty IS NOT NULL] AS temp
RETURN temp
```

The weird thing is this always return me a list null. But with only one condition then it will work, like only find objects in the list or only thirdParty is not null.
But combine the 2 conditions together, it will always return a list of null.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UNWIND` seems to return a list of maps, not a map. But the good thing is that with apoc, you can convert it easily.

this works:

```
WITH [
        [
            {
                thirdParty: "Supermarkets"
            },
            {
                category: "Groceries"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                category: "Rent"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                thirdParty: "Education"
            },
            {
                category: "Education"
            }
        ]
    ]
AS tagsList

WITH tagsList, ['Groceries','Subscription TV','Telecommunications'] as list
UNWIND tagsList as tags
WITH list,
     apoc.map.fromPairs(
        REDUCE(arr=[],tag IN tags | 
               arr+[[keys(tag)[0],tag[keys(tag)[0]]]]
        )
     ) AS tagMap
WHERE tagMap.category IN list AND tagMap.thirdParty IS NOT NULL
RETURN tagMap
```

returns

```
{
  "thirdParty": "Supermarkets",
  "category": "Groceries"
}
```